# TeamCity missing references on ARM/x64 platforms

Tags: teamcity

When I compile with Mixed Platforms (Any CPU/x86), my TeamCity build works fine. However, when I switch to x64 and ARM it *strangely* loses the references. What did I miss? Here is the CSC that TeamCity ends up running. Inside VS, everything works fine. Note that the References missed are Portable Libraries. Could that be the issue?

Mixed Platforms:

```
[Csc] ...Csc.exe ... /reference:D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e8875ba979c63c78\bin\Release\Mvx\Portable\Cirrious.CrossCore.dll /reference:D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\e8875ba979c63c78\bin\Release\Mvx\Portable\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.dll /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Collections.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Globalization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.IO.Compression.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.IO.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Linq.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Linq.Expressions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Linq.Parallel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Linq.Queryable.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.Http.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.Http.Rtc.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.Requests.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Numerics.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ObjectModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Reflection.Context.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Reflection.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Security.Principal.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.Http.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.NetTcp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.Security.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Text.Encoding.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Threading.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Threading.Tasks.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Windows.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.Serialization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.XDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd" /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 /optimize+ /out:obj\x86\Release\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll /subsystemversion:6.00 /target:library /utf8output ..\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite\SharedFile\SQLiteAsync.cs ..\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite\SharedFile\SQLiteNet.cs MvxStoreSQLiteConnectionFactory.cs Plugin.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\.NETCore,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
[11:42:03]
```

ARM (fails with missing namespace, etc. - and it is missing those references):

```
[Csc] ...Csc.exe ... /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\Microsoft.CSharp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\mscorlib.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Collections.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Core.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Globalization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.IO.Compression.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.IO.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Linq.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Linq.Expressions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Linq.Parallel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Linq.Queryable.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.Http.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.Http.Rtc.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Net.Requests.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Numerics.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ObjectModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Reflection.Context.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Reflection.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Security.Principal.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.Http.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.NetTcp.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.Security.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Text.Encoding.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Threading.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Threading.Tasks.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Windows.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.Serialization.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.XDocument.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll" /reference:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd" /debug:pdbonly /filealign:512 /optimize+ /out:obj\ARM\Release\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite.WindowsStore.dll /subsystemversion:6.02 /target:library /utf8output ..\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite\SharedFile\SQLiteAsync.cs ..\Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.Sqlite\SharedFile\SQLiteNet.cs MvxStoreSQLiteConnectionFactory.cs Plugin.cs Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs "D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp\.NETCore,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.cs"
[11:42:20]
```

**Update.** A workaround is to check "build" on the Any CPU projects that are needed in the x64 and ARM platform configurations. TeamCity ends up rebuilding them, but everything seems to work afterwards. I suspect the build happens not in the checkout dir as claimed but somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is the TeamCity MSBuild agent is doing exactly what it's been told to do. In Visual Studio if Build->Configuration Manager is set to NOT build your project under x86 then it won't build it. As a matter of course when you add new projects to a solution then you need to cycle through each relevant solution configuration/platform configuration pair and ensure the appropriate projects are set to build appropriately. This is especially important on a CI build server which potentially has never built the solution in any configuration previously. On your dev box VS will find (often inappropriately) dll's left over from previous builds. Consider the difference between build and rebuild.